# Difference between "EMV" and "Global Platform"

Tags: smartcard

I would like to ask if someone of you know the difference between "EMV" and "Global Platform".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global Platform - which is cross platform, but has Java Card as its main platform - is a platform to manage applications (Java Card Applets) on cards. It includes authentication schemes and authorization of additional "security domains", that may manage applications.

EMV is the standard created by Europay, MasterCard and VISA (the E, M and V in the scheme) for interoperability of smart cards and POS (point of sale) terminals. As GlobalPlatform, Java Card is often used for the contact / contactless or dual contact chips in Debit and Credit cards.

In short, GP implements a card management specification and  provides services (such as secure channels) to applications. EMV defines the interface for banking cards.

Neither of the specifications define the runtime system of the card, although GP for instance does provide an on card interface for Java Card Applets to use.

Comment: I do not think the part "Java card applets" is correct. The Global Platform is  “a cross-industry, non-profit association which identifies, develops and publishes specifications that promote the secure and interoperable deployment and management of multiple applications on secure chip technology.”. A good example of non-java is the Apple joined the GlobalPlatfom and became a full member of the organization in 2014. I am pretty sure Apple will try its best to avoid anything about "Java" on board its OSs.

Comment: @r0ng This is true, I should have edited that in long ago.

Comment: Are there examples of other platforms for which Global Platform operates on? (Is it something like 95% Java Cards? Other than them, I only know of the Basic Card used by GPG as another in-use smartcard plaftform.) Also, is Apple a member because of their Apple card (issued by MasterCard) or their Apple Pay, or some other reason?

Comment: I don't have any information on the Apple question (and Apple really is a secretive company in lots of ways, so they may not even share this kind of information). I don't think that there are any other current Global Platform implementations. There are a few other platforms such as MultOS and possibly a few file based systems such as CardOS (although the latest press release by the current owner was from 2016 and only sideways mentioned the system, it's not hip new technology).

Answer (score 2):

Global Platform is a standard for defining life cycle, authentication, secure channels and domain separation on smart card products. A Java Card can be a Global Platform card, but also a MULTOS card can be Global Platform compliant.

EMV is a payment industry standard on which payment applications are based on. So your banking card or credit card with chip is based on EMV standard.

A credit card with chip can be a Global Platform card which holds an EMV application.

Answer (score 0):

EMV is a chip-card standard that was developed to encompass existing credit-card implementations by (now defunct) Europay, MasterCard and Visa.  Chips that are EMV compliant are limited in a certain sense versus the more general intended implementation, that is now Global Platform.  In other words, Global Platform is a more general, extensible and accommodating standard than EMV, although EMV is the standard that currently dominates the actual market.

The idea is that the card you're currently using is EMV, but can only really be used to make payments for a single bank, whereas a global platform card could be used for non-banking purposes [like as a SIM for a mobile phone type device], and for banking/payment purposes could also be used to hold all your old plastic cards, not just the ones from a single banks.

Answer (score 0):

EMV is a payment application. Global Platform (GP) is a platform in Java.

When there is a Java applet developed, the applet can be downloaded into GP and works. So, you can develop any kind of applets, if the memory space is enough, then applets can be download into GP and run.

EMV is such a Java applet but focused on credit/debit card application. But, most of time, EMV is default built in GP card and therefore most of GP card can run EMV. But, if you do not want to run EMV, you can forget the default EMV applet inside and just run your own applet on GP.

Comment: No. EMV is a payment standard, not so much an application or Applet. GP itself is not a "platform in Java", it is a protocol to manage libraries and applications, mainly focussing on life cycle management (including authentication). It does not provide an entire platform - that's what e.g. Java Card platforms are for. You are confusing protocols and applications that implement the protocols.

Comment: the answer is completely false and erroneous but it has the higher amount of votes .. mmm

Answer (score 0):

EMV is for defining **payment environment** and let different entities to operate together. Every single entity must comply with the rules. Those entities are , Smartcard, terminals(POS, ATM), Banks and Chip Card Applications. 
Global Platform is for defining **Smartcard** standarts not the payment system. With those rules every entity(chip manufacturers, Chip OS Vendors) can operate together. They can set their smartcard personalization, authentication rules etc.

Answer (score 0):

in a nutshell EMV and globalplatform has nothing to do with each other , EMV is a generic term to define an alliance between three companies Europay-Mastercard-Visa to create a group of standards to fight frauds against payment cards.

Global Platform is a set of abstract specifications that define how to do secure application management.

The norms related to EMV makes an extensive use of the global platform specifications in order to manage the payment application on the cards so that the global platform is historically linked to EMV but the two terms are different by essence.